# How can I create a deep neural network which has a capability to take a decision for hypothesis?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, deep-learning

Basically, I am interested in solving a hypothesis problem, where I am only aware of the data distribution of a null hypothesis and don't know anything about the alternative case.

My concern is how should I train my deep neural network so that it can classify or recognise whether a particular sample data has a similar distribution as in null hypothesis case or it's from another class(An alternative Hypothesis case).

According to my understanding, It's different from a binary classification (one vs all case), because in that case, we know what data we are going to tackle, but here in my case alternative hypothesis case can follow any data distribution.

Here I am giving you an example situation, what I want exactly

---

**Suppose I want to predict that a person is likely to have cancer or not**

**e.g**

I have a data set of the factors that cause cancer like,

`Parameter A=1,Parameter B=3.87,Parameter C=5.6,Has cancer = yes`

But I don't have a data set where

`Parameter A=2,Parameter B=1.87,Parameter C=2.6,Has cancer = No`

---

Can be anything like this

Means I don't know about anything which leads to a conclusion of not having cancer, can I still train my model to recognise whether a person has cancer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure enough that the alternative hypothesis data come from different distribution than the null hypothesis, you can try unsupervised learning algorithm. i.e a K-mean or a GMM with the right number of cluster could yield a great separation of the data. You can then assign label to the second class data and train a classifier using it.

This a general approach of semi-supervised learning.

Another idea would be to consider the alternative hypothesis data as outliers and use anomalie detection algorithm to find you second class data point. This is much more difficult to achieve and rely heavily on the supposition that data comes from really different distribution.

Comment: Hello, Sir, you have mentioned that I can apply semi-supervised learning approach but I want my Deep neural network to be robust for all kind of data means I want that it can take a decision for the data which it does not have encounter till now as well, so in that approach how can I apply semi-supervised approach. can you explain me in details?

Comment: Every model in general is built to make decision over data it has encountered before. The goal from using semi supervised learning is to assign label to your second class data (alternative hypothesis), then you can build your classifier using neural net or any other classification algorithm. I know that something exist for semi supervised neural net and is called **ladder networks** but labelling data from both class is still necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is kind of Yes and No...

If you don't know anything about the distribution of data points in alternative hypotheses they could in principle be indistinguishably close to your known distribution, therefor you would always classify them (wrongly) as "myHypothesis". That was the No part.

For the Yes part: What you can do is excluding data-sets that are sufficiently different from your hypothesis to make it unlikely that they are generated by the same distribution. This means in principle you can then make a statement like "the probability of `myDistribution` generating the given data is less then `some value`".

However I don't think that a neural-net is necessarily the best way to make such a statement. It could be sufficient, to fit a model (ideally a known model... so if you know what exact distribution you have you should use that and fit the parameters rather than using a neural net) to your training-data and then just calculate the probability (for instance using Bayesian Inference) of observing your test data given your model. For more info you can check out something like [this](http://ipython-books.github.io/featured-07/)